# If you are writing a long passage in past perfect, is it acceptable to only use it at the beginning and end?

Tags: grammaticality, tense

Let's say that you're writing a long passage in past perfect, like a flashback or a memory. Is it considered acceptable to only use past perfect for the sentences at the beginning and end of the passage and then switch to past simple for the rest?

I ask because it gets tedious to both read and write so many "had"s...

Comment: You probably wouldn't repeat the past perfect at the end, but it's sometimes acceptable to "set the stage" with the past perfect and then continue in the simple past. A sample passage would help to answer this question.

Comment: I think that if you make it clear that it's a flashback or memory, you can write the whole thing in the simple past.

Comment: It depends. Would you give us an example?

Answer (score 1):

Past some point it's not as much about what is *grammatical* or *appropriate* as what, exactly you are *trying to say*.  Repeated words are *emphasized* in some way, to illustrate a point.  For example:

> The young governess was upset.  After all, she **had been** the one to get the children to write their Christmas lists, and it was she who **had gone** to the store, she who **had done** the shopping, she who **had carted** all the presents home, she who **had** carefully **wrapped** each, and she who **had placed** them decoratively under the tree.  She didn't expect the children to **have given** her thanks, lost in their own selfish worlds as children are, but she did expect the parents to **have shown** some gratitude.

The repetition of "had" in this passage emphasizes all the various effort the governess made to buy presents for the children, to legitimize her annoyance.  The writer might use this to illuminate the subject's train of thought, how each effort compounded the insult.

It could easily be written in the way you describe:

> After all, she **had been** the one to make it a nice Christmas for the family: she got the children to write their Christmas lists, went to the store, did the shopping, carted all the presents home, carefully wrapped each, and placed them decoratively under the tree, and yet the parents **had not given** her any word of thanks.

This is more or less the same as the previous passage, but without the extra emphasis.